# LINQ to entity query, check null before using navigation property

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

Please look at this simplified LINQ query:

```
var lst = from pat in ctx.PATIENTS
          join cons in ctx.CONSULTATIONS.Include(a => a.EXAMENS)
          on pat.ID_PATIENT equals cons.CON_ID_PATIENT into joinpatcons
          from p in joinpatcons.DefaultIfEmpty()
          select new ConsultationsPageType()
          {
              ID_CONSULTATION = (p == null) ? 0 : p.ID_CONSULTATION
          };
```

The `ID_CONSULTATION` field is a nullable `int`:

```
public class ConsultationsPageType
{
    //......
    public int? ID_CONSULTATION { get; set; }
    //......
}
```

What I want is to return `null` instead of zero, if `p` is `null`. Replacing simply `0` by `null` gave me this error:

> Unable to determine the conditional expression type because there is
>   no implicit conversion between  and intentre  and int

And `p?.ID_CONSULTATION` gave me this error:

> A lambda expression arborecence can not contain a null propagation
>   operator

I am on .NET 4.6.

Comment: So what's hard in changing it to `ID_CONSULTATION = (p == null) ? null : p.ID_CONSULTATION`? Am I missing something?

Comment: sorry, please look at the edited question

Comment: You can cast the `null` to `int?`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply change the zero to `null` and cast it to `int?`:

```
ID_CONSULTATION = (p == null ? (int?)null : p.ID_CONSULTATION)
```